# HTML Clickable Table Rows

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter's Bootstrap, which includes a neat hover effect for table rows, and I would like to add the clickability that users will expect when a row lights up.  Is there any foolproof way to do this?

Yes I've done my research, but every solution is extremely awkward and flawed at best.  Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: So what do you want? The tables rows to be able to be clicked after they light up?

Comment: What is this click supposed to do?

Comment: Stuff you cannot possibly fathom, @Diodeus...  Stuff you cannot possibly fathom.

Comment: `Yes I've done my research` You also have to post it.

Comment: You need to specify what you mean by add the clickability, any element on the page is clickable, you just need to know what to do with that click.

Comment: Sorry - I think @MikeChristensen gets the picture (lol) - this will have many uses, immediately I just want a standard link.  If I could just wrap the whole thing in an anchor tag I would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although my Google-skills are pretty awesome this is something most people should find... 
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquey-make-entire-table-row-clickable/

But, to make it a lot easier... What about simply giving the row an id and assigning a link to that id with jQuery?

```
<table>
<tr id='link1'>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
    <td>four</td>
</tr>
<tr id='link2'>
    <td>two-one</td>
    <td>two-two</td>
    <td>two-three</td>
    <td>two-four</td>
</tr>
</table>​
```

​and

```
$("#link1").click(function(){
window.location = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115550/html-clickable-table-rows";
});
$("#link2").click(function(){
window.location = "http:///stackoverflow.com";
});
```

also see this: http://jsfiddle.net/avrZG/
​

Comment: Simple enough, thank you!  I really did look around, and didn't post research here because most of what I found was kinda useless and shouldn't necessarily be repeated.

Answer (score 3):

**The HTML**

```
<table id="example">
<tr>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Price</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="apples">Edit</a></td>
    <td>Apples</td>
    <td>Blah blah blah blah</td>
    <td>10.23</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="bananas">Edit</a></td>
    <td>Bananas</td>
    <td>Blah blah blah blah</td>
    <td>11.45</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="oranges">Edit</a></td>
    <td>Oranges</td>
    <td>Blah blah blah blah</td>
    <td>12.56</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**The CSS**

```
table#example {
    border-collapse: collapse;   
}
#example tr {
    background-color: #eee;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}
#example tr:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
#example th {
    background-color: #fff;
}
#example th, #example td {
    padding: 3px 5px;
}
#example td:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**The jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example tr').click(function() {
        var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        if(href) {
            window.location = href;
        }
    });

});
```

I got the code [HERE](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquey-make-entire-table-row-clickable/)

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery:

```
<table>
<tr id='link1' onclick="document.location='http://stackoverflow.com/about';">
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
    <td>four</td>
</tr>
<tr id='link2' onclick="document.location='http://stackoverflow.com/help';">
    <td>two-one</td>
    <td>two-two</td>
    <td>two-three</td>
    <td>two-four</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what you are trying to do but you probably want the following. Adding a tabindex to the tr elements will work in most browsers and make it possible to set focus on a row via mouse click or keyboard tab.

```
<table>
    <tr id='link1' tabindex="100">
        <td>one</td>
        <td>two</td>
        <td>three</td>
        <td>four</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='link2' tabindex="101">
        <td>two-one</td>
        <td>two-two</td>
        <td>two-three</td>
        <td>two-four</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```